# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'void *' to param

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting the above error (can't figure out how to see tail end of the error) from the following code:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\n" options:nil error:nil];
```

Can someone tell me what this error means (and how to see the end of it)? I do know some C++, but even knowing some C++ and some Objective-C I don't know what my `void *` is or how I'm using it inappropriately.

Comment: tail end is probably 'parameter of typeNSRegularExpressionOptions'

Comment: To see the tail end of the error in Xcode, show the Navigator Pane, and within the Navigation Pane, select the "Issue navigator" (rounded triangle with an exclamation point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 0 instead of `nil` for `options`. Even though both are conceptually the same, `options` takes in integers (`NSRegularExpressionOptions` enum) while `nil` is `(void *)0`.